# When to Ask for Location During Sign Up

Tags: mobile-web, signup-signon, webforms, location, location-service

I'm working on an app that sends technicians to fix problems. Think of it like Uber for repairs.

The service is only available in a select few cities, and the way the sign-up process right now is that they ask for an address before any details and if the area is serviceable, then the user enters all of their details, describe the problem, then billing info. (Option A)

I think this process is clunky and frustrating, but you'll know immediately if your location can't be served.

The other option (Option B) is to get all the info up top, then get the location before billing. This is also frustrating because you fill out information that doesn't matter unless you live in the right area.

Is there a solution that makes sense? would the frustration be solved by adding a label to the address field in Option A that says something like "Check your location for availability"?[image: Sign Up Flows]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion:

I'm not sure what fields of the address you are collecting.  I would see if you can limit the entry to **Zip Code** or **City**.

That's a low point of friction that pinpoints the location of the user, while providing them the immediate value.

**For example:**
Enter your city / zip code to find technicians in your area.
[City] or [Zip Code Field]

Simple, and as a user I know why you're asking for it, and understand I get immediate value by providing it.

As a bonus, if you make it an input field, you can collect cities that users enter to gauge interest.  You can even tell the user "We're not available in your city yet.  Get notified when (app name) is available in (insert city name).  [Enter your email]